# Firebase User Authentication, firebase.auth().uid is undefined even though user signed in

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

Client side: I'm trying the create an ajax call to the routes thats supposed to pass on the user uid information to the server side. The user is signed in with firebase facebook and I used the firebase log in template to do so.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/meals/putMeal',
  type: 'PUT',
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: JSON.stringify({testMeal: testMealData, userID: authData.uid}),
  success:function(result){
    alert(result);
  }
});
```

Server Side, I was just checking the userID however it returned undefined. I also tested getting firebase.auth().uid on the server side and it also returned undefined. The user is definitely logged in.

```
router.put('/putMeal',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log("req body is " + req.body.testMeal.Name);
    console.log("the user is " + req.body.userID);
}); //CREATE
```

Comment: Are you sure authData.uid is actually defined data? If so, are you using body-parser middleware server-side? Express, for example, uses the body-parser middleware to enable easy access to the req.body object.

Comment: There's not enough information for us to help you troubleshoot here. Check right before the `$.ajax` call what the value of authData.uid is. If it is undefined (which I suspect), the user is not authenticated yet and you can ignore the node.js side for the moment. If that is the case and you still need help, share the [minimal-but-complete code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which at the least will also include a call that signs in to Firebase.

Comment: firebase.auth().uid is not defined. To get the current user uid, you have to call firebase.auth().currentUser.uid